# Ordenação de vetor de vetores de caracteres com qsort <cstdlib>

Tags: c++, array-multidimensional, quicksort

O programa seguinte não está ordenando o vetor de vetores de chars corretamente, mas não sei por que. Talvez seja minha função auxiliar "cmpstr" que não está retornando o valor certo em alguns casos, ou minha chamada do qsort...O que está errado?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> //qsort
#include <cstring> //strcmp
using namespace std;

int cmpstr(const void* a, const void* b){ // função auxiliar do qsort
    const char* aa = (const char*)a;
    const char* bb = (const char*)b;
    return strcmp(aa, bb);
}

char equipe[1000][5000][50]; //array de arrays de arrays de caracteres

int main()
{
    int qtd_alunos, qtd_times, qtd_membros;
    cin>>qtd_alunos>>qtd_times;
    qtd_membros = qtd_alunos/qtd_times;

    for(int j=0; j<qtd_membros; j++){   //recebe nomes
        for(int i=0; i<qtd_times; i++){
            cin>>equipe[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int j=0; j<qtd_times; j++){  //ordena cada equipe [deveria ordenar]
        qtd_membros = qtd_alunos/qtd_times;
        qsort(equipe[j], qtd_membros, sizeof(char*), cmpstr);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<qtd_times; i++){  //exibe a composição de cada equipe
        cout<<"Time "<<i+1<<'\n';
        qtd_membros = qtd_alunos/qtd_times;
        for(int j=0; j<qtd_membros;j++){
            cout<<equipe[i][j]<<'\n';
        }
        cout<<'\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Talvez não seja a resposta que deseja, mas vou dar a que é e melhor solução.

Está usando C++, certo? Então use C++. Não use C. Se não sabia dessa diferença, está aprendendo agora. Se alguém lhe mandou fazer assim, melhor começar escutar outras pessoas.

Use [`sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) no lugar do `qsort`. Aí aproveita e usa [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) no lugar de *array*, ou pelo menos [`array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Pode ser que já resolva seu problema. Se isto não ocorrer, pelo menos poderá fzer um pergunta em cima de uma boa base de código.